# PDO rowCount for exisiting usernames

Tags: php, pdo

How can I correctly set my code to where two same username cannot be registered? The current code I have now is letting me register the username over and over again repeatedly! Here is my current code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        if(empty($_POST['username'])){
            $errors[] = 'Username is required.';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['password'])){
            $errors[] = 'Password is required.';
        }

        if(empty($errors)){
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username";
            $check = dbConnect()->prepare($query);
            $check->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
            $check->execute();

            if($check->rowCount() > 0){
                $errors[] = 'The chosen username is already registered.';
            }

            if(empty($errors)){
                $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password) VALUES (:username,:password)";
                $query = dbConnect()->prepare($query);
                $query->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
                $query->bindValue(':password', $_POST['password']);

                if(!$query->execute()){
                    $errors[] = 'Query failed to execute.';
                } else {
                    header('Location: index.php');
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of unique restriction is best left up to the database.  If two users try to register at the same time with the same username, your code will fail.  In between the time of checking for availability and inserting a new row, it's possible for a username to become unavailable.

Set a UNIQUE constraint on that column.

Comment: If i set the username filed as unique, how then can I set an error saying something like "that username is already taken". ?

Comment: @DaNgSayz Put it in a try catch block and handle the specific exception that comes back.  (You've configured PDO to throw exceptions, right?)

Comment: So just basically wrap that code in a try{} ? PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ?

Comment: @DaNgSayz Exactly.  Wrap your query code in a `try`/`catch` block. And make sure you have `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` somewhere.

Comment: Got it! my error is working: it is say ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'hi' for key 'username' but is there a way I can customize that message? to something like "sorry! that username is taken". ??

Comment: @DaNgSayz Yeah, don't echo out the actual exception itself.  Echo out a different message.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rowCount` is useless for `SELECT` queries - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php. Ways of solving you problem are described in this manual too.

Comment: That depends on the driver.